# Redirect BroadcastReceiver onReceive()

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

What's the correct way (if any) to redirect a received Intent to another BroadcastReceiver?

I have two BroadcastReceivers set to listen to the same intent.  It works in development, but in production, only the first one registered in the manifest gets the intent.

Can I call the other one's onReceive() method directly, passing the same context and intent?  Is there a better way to pass the intent along once the first receiver is done with it?

**EDIT** - I never figured out how to do this generically, but I came up with a solution.  I wrote it up on my blog and it's pretty long so, [insert shameless plug to my answer here](http://www.xn--w-mer-iza4o.com/2010/11/07/intercepting-google-analytics-referrer-tracking-on-android/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an ordered broadcast

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendOrderedBroadcast%28android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sending the original broadcast.  If I were to do that from my registered receiver, I think it might cause an infinite loop, no?

Comment: Oh, I my mistake, I thought you were sending it. Well there's 2 issues I see. 1.) Why do you have 2 receivers listening to the same intent? 2.) Are you sure it's not a bug in your code such that your second receiver isn't getting the intent?

Comment: Yes, I'm intercepting Google Analytics' installation intent broadcast.  When I test it by broadcasting my own intent, both receivers get it.  When the app goes live, however, only Google's receiver gets it.  I've fixed this by only registering my own, and calling Google's onReceive() method manually.

Comment: This doesn't *really* answer my specific question, but it's good advice generally so I'll accept it.  Going to edit the question to link to my ultimate solution to this specific problem.